# How to generate Keywords from Keywords Planner API (Google Ads API) in PHP

Tags: php, google-api, google-ads-api

I'm making Web Application for Extracting data from Youtube Videos then analyze it and find the best keywords

All I need is finding the best keywords from Keywords Planner of Google depends on the volume search i did extract the youtube video data, I followed this library
https://github.com/googleads/googleads-php-lib

I have Clientid, Clientsecret and Developer Token After I installed the library successfully
and tried to test GetCampaigns() class, I get this Error

```
Fatal error: Uncaught InvalidArgumentException: All of 'clientId', 'clientSecret', and 'refreshToken' must be set when using installed/web application flow. in C:\xampp\htdocs\seosystem\googleads-php-lib\src\Google\AdsApi\Common\OAuth2TokenBuilder.php:225 Stack trace: #0 C:\xampp\htdocs\seosystem\googleads-php-lib\src\Google\AdsApi\Common\OAuth2TokenBuilder.php(173): Google\AdsApi\Common\OAuth2TokenBuilder->validate() #1 C:\xampp\htdocs\seosystem\googleads-php-lib\examples\AdWords\v201809\BasicOperations\GetCampaigns.php(81): Google\AdsApi\Common\OAuth2TokenBuilder->build() #2 C:\xampp\htdocs\seosystem\googleads-php-lib\examples\AdWords\v201809\BasicOperations\GetCampaigns.php(90): Google\AdsApi\Examples\AdWords\v201809\BasicOperations\GetCampaigns::main() #3 C:\xampp\htdocs\seosystem\index.php(4): require_once('C:\\xampp\\htdocs...') #4 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\seosystem\googleads-php-lib\src\Google\AdsApi\Common\OAuth2TokenBuilder.php on line 225
```

I went to OAuth2TokenBuilder and replaced and still get the same Error Message no worries i'll change the key later

```
 private $clientId ='847786194979-n0udvkdi41r9fd5arlma6gadlm2kueot.apps.googleusercontent.com';
private $clientSecret ='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';
private $refreshToken ='Af8L57gifnGl1b4M324_Tg';
```

and this's the whole file

```
<?php
/**
 * Copyright 2016 Google Inc. All Rights Reserved.
 *
 * Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License");
 * you may not use this file except in compliance with the License.
 * You may obtain a copy of the License at
 *
 *     http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
 *
 * Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
 * distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
 * WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
 * See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
 * limitations under the License.
 */

namespace Google\AdsApi\Common;

use Google\Auth\Credentials\ServiceAccountCredentials;
use Google\Auth\Credentials\UserRefreshCredentials;
use InvalidArgumentException;

/**
 * Builds OAuth2 access token fetchers.
 *
 * @see FetchAuthTokenInterface
 */
final class OAuth2TokenBuilder implements AdsBuilder
{

    private $configurationLoader;

    private $jsonKeyFilePath;
    private $scopes;
    private $impersonatedEmail;

    private $clientId ='847786194979-n0udvkdi41r9fd5arlma6gadlm2kueot.apps.googleusercontent.com';
    private $clientSecret ='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';
    private $refreshToken ='Af8L57gifnGl1b4M324_Tg';

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->configurationLoader = new ConfigurationLoader();
    }

    /**
     * Reads configuration settings from the specified filepath. The filepath is
     * optional, and if omitted, it will look for the default configuration
     * filename in the home directory of the user running PHP.
     *
     * @see AdsBuilder::DEFAULT_CONFIGURATION_FILENAME
     *
     * @param string $path the filepath
     * @return OAuth2TokenBuilder this builder populated from the configuration
     * @throws InvalidArgumentException if the configuration file could not be
     *     found
     */
    public function fromFile($path = null)
    {
        if ($path === null) {
            $path = self::DEFAULT_CONFIGURATION_FILENAME;
        }

        return $this->from($this->configurationLoader->fromFile($path));
    }

    /**
     * @see AdsBuilder::from()
     */
    public function from(Configuration $configuration)
    {
        $this->jsonKeyFilePath = $configuration->getConfiguration('jsonKeyFilePath', 'OAUTH2');
        $this->scopes = $configuration->getConfiguration('scopes', 'OAUTH2');
        $this->impersonatedEmail = $configuration->getConfiguration('impersonatedEmail', 'OAUTH2');
        $this->clientId = $configuration->getConfiguration('clientId', 'OAUTH2');
        $this->clientSecret = $configuration->getConfiguration('clientSecret', 'OAUTH2');
        $this->refreshToken = $configuration->getConfiguration('refreshToken', 'OAUTH2');

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Includes an absolute path to an OAuth2 JSON key file when using service
     * account flow. Required and only applicable when using service account flow.
     *
     * @param string|null $jsonKeyFilePath
     * @return OAuth2TokenBuilder this builder
     */
    public function withJsonKeyFilePath($jsonKeyFilePath)
    {
        $this->jsonKeyFilePath = $jsonKeyFilePath;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Includes OAuth2 scopes. Required and only applicable when using service
     * account flow.
     *
     * @param string|null $scopes a space-delimited list of scopes
     * @return OAuth2TokenBuilder this builder
     */
    public function withScopes($scopes)
    {
        $this->scopes = $scopes;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Includes an email of account to impersonate when using service account
     * flow. Optional and only applicable when using service account flow.
     *
     * @param string|null $impersonatedEmail
     * @return OAuth2TokenBuilder this builder
     */
    public function withImpersonatedEmail($impersonatedEmail)
    {
        $this->impersonatedEmail = $impersonatedEmail;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Includes an OAuth2 client ID. Required when using installed application or
     * web application flow.
     *
     * @param string|null $clientId
     * @return OAuth2TokenBuilder this builder
     */
    public function withClientId($clientId)
    {
        $this->clientId = $clientId;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Includes an OAuth2 client secret. Required when using installed application
     * or web application flow.
     *
     * @param string|null $clientSecret
     * @return OAuth2TokenBuilder this builder
     */
    public function withClientSecret($clientSecret)
    {
        $this->clientSecret = $clientSecret;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Includes an OAuth2 refresh token. Required when using installed application
     * or web application flow.
     *
     * @param string|null $refreshToken
     * @return OAuth2TokenBuilder this builder
     */
    public function withRefreshToken($refreshToken)
    {
        $this->refreshToken = $refreshToken;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * @see AdsBuilder::build()
     */
    public function build()
    {
        $this->defaultOptionals();
        $this->validate();

        if ($this->jsonKeyFilePath !== null) {
            return new ServiceAccountCredentials(
                $this->scopes,
                $this->jsonKeyFilePath,
                $this->impersonatedEmail
            );
        } else {
            return new UserRefreshCredentials(
                null,
                [
                    'client_id' => $this->clientId,
                    'client_secret' => $this->clientSecret,
                    'refresh_token' => $this->refreshToken
                ]
            );
        }
    }

    /**
     * @see AdsBuilder::defaultOptionals()
     */
    public function defaultOptionals()
    {
        // Nothing to default for this builder.
    }

    /**
     * @see AdsBuilder::validate()
     */
    public function validate()
    {
        if (($this->jsonKeyFilePath !== null || $this->scopes !== null)
            && ($this->clientId !== null || $this->clientSecret !== null
                || $this->refreshToken !== null)) {
            throw new InvalidArgumentException(
                'Cannot have both service account '
                . 'flow and installed/web application flow credential values set.'
            );
        }

        if ($this->jsonKeyFilePath !== null || $this->scopes !== null) {
            if ($this->jsonKeyFilePath === null || $this->scopes === null) {
                throw new InvalidArgumentException(
                    'Both \'jsonKeyFilePath\' and '
                    . '\'scopes\' must be set when using service account flow.'
                );
            }
        } elseif ($this->clientId === null
            || $this->clientSecret === null
            || $this->refreshToken === null) {
            throw new InvalidArgumentException(
                'All of \'clientId\', '
                . '\'clientSecret\', and \'refreshToken\' must be set when using '
                . 'installed/web application flow.'
            );
        }
    }

    /**
     * Gets the JSON key file path.
     *
     * @return string|null
     */
    public function getJsonKeyFilePath()
    {
        return $this->jsonKeyFilePath;
    }

    /**
     * Gets the scopes.
     *
     * @return string|null
     */
    public function getScopes()
    {
        return $this->scopes;
    }

    /**
     * Gets the impersonated email.
     *
     * @return string|null
     */
    public function getImpersonatedEmail()
    {
        return $this->impersonatedEmail;
    }

    /**
     * Gets the client ID.
     *
     * @return string|null
     */
    public function getClientId()
    {
        return $this->clientId;
    }

    /**
     * Gets the client secret.
     *
     * @return string|null
     */
    public function getClientSecret()
    {
        return $this->clientSecret;
    }

    /**
     * Gets the refresh token.
     *
     * @return string|null
     */
    public function getRefreshToken()
    {
        return $this->refreshToken;
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you show how you are using this code?

Comment: Specifically how you are invoking it.

Comment: `<?php
require 'bootstrap/view.php';
require_once('googleads-php-lib\examples\AdWords\v201809\BasicOperations\GetCampaigns.php');
$getcamp = new GetCampaigns(); `

This's how am i using GetCampaigns Class

Comment: You posted a block of code that is almost 300 lines. That code can have those values overwritten in several ways. I am trying to see how you are using the block of code that has the error message. Whatever you just posted might be using it, but I can’t see that.

Comment: This's how am i using GetCampaigns Class
This in index.php the main file I sumbited an issue on the library some of google fellows says the libary will be deleted in the next year